# How to calculate day difference using Angular.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help. I need to calculate difference between two day fields using Angular.js/Javascript.I am explaining my code below.

```
<select class="form-control" id="daysFrom" ng-model="daysFrom" ng-change="getSubcategoryValue('daysFrom');">
<option value="" label="Select Day" selected="selected">Select Day</option>
<option value="1" label="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="2" label="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3" label="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4" label="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="5" label="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="6" label="Saturday">Saturday</option>
<option value="7" label="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

My second day drop down is given below.

```
<select class="form-control" id="daysTo" ng-model="daysFrom" ng-change="getSubcategoryValue('daysFrom');">
    <option value="" label="Select Day" selected="selected">Select Day</option>
    <option value="1" label="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="2" label="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3" label="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4" label="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5" label="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="6" label="Saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="7" label="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>
```

Here i have two dropdown like `day from and day to`. I need when user will select two day the difference should calculate including those days. Suppose user selected first `Monday and wednesday`,it should calculate as `3` in difference. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var difference=abs(parseInt($scope.daysTo)-parseInt($scope.daysFrom))+1;
```

Comment: If day range will be like this `sunday to Monday`.

Comment: var difference=abs((parseInt($scope.daysTo) % 7)-(parseInt($scope.daysFrom)%7))+1;

Comment: check your post again

Comment: var difference=abs((parseInt($scope.daysTo)!=7?parseInt($scope.daysTo) % 7:0)-(parseInt($scope.daysFrom)!=7?parseInt($scope.daysFrom)%7:7))+1;

Comment: your answer is working properly .Add it to your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the first input `dayFrom` and the second input `dayTo` then:

```
function calculateDifference(dayFrom, dayTo) {
    return Math.abs(dayTo + dayFrom) + 1;
}

var difference = calculateDifference($scope.dayFrom, $scope.dayTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#daysFrom, #daysTo').change(function(){    
    if ($('#daysTo').val() < $('#daysFrom').val())
    {
      console.log("Wrong day choose");
      return false;
    }
    console.log($('#daysTo').val() - $('#daysFrom').val()+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From : <select class="form-control" id="daysFrom" ng-model="daysFrom" ng-change="getSubcategoryValue('daysFrom');">
<option value="" label="Select Day" selected="selected">Select Day</option>
<option value="1" label="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="2" label="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3" label="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4" label="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="5" label="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="6" label="Saturday">Saturday</option>
<option value="7" label="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
To : <select class="form-control" id="daysTo" ng-model="daysFrom" ng-change="getSubcategoryValue('daysFrom');">
    <option value="" label="Select Day" selected="selected">Select Day</option>
    <option value="1" label="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="2" label="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3" label="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4" label="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5" label="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="6" label="Saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="7" label="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: check your answer again.

Comment: @subhra: what's the problem with my answer, if you want to show "+1" you can add it on value

Comment: Can you see the console to see the calculated difference ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any angular so I show how You can manage that in pure js:

```js
(function(){

//private scope
 
//variables - DOM references
var output=document.querySelector("#output");
var from=document.querySelector("#daysFrom");
var to=document.querySelector("#daysTo");

//error codes
var ERROR_CHOOSE=-1;
var ERROR_DIFF=-2;

//calculates
function calcDiff(){
  
  if (to.value==="" || from.value==="")
  return ERROR_CHOOSE;
  
  if (to.value<from.value)
  return ERROR_DIFF;
  
  return to.value-from.value+1;
  
};

//return human results
function display(){

    var result=calcDiff();

    if (result>0){ //we know no error
      
        if (result==1)
        return result+=" day";
        else
            return result+=" days";
    }

    //here errors

    return result==ERROR_CHOOSE?"Choose both days":"Choose right days";
};


//usage example
from.addEventListener("change",function(){

  output.innerText=display();
  
});

to.addEventListener("change",function(){

  output.innerText=display();
  
});
 
})();
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="daysFrom" ng-model="daysFrom" ng-change="getSubcategoryValue('daysFrom');">
<option value="" label="Select Day" selected="selected">Select Day</option>
<option value="1" label="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="2" label="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3" label="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4" label="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="5" label="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="6" label="Saturday">Saturday</option>
<option value="7" label="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="daysTo" ng-model="daysFrom" ng-change="getSubcategoryValue('daysFrom');">
<option value="" label="Select Day" selected="selected">Select Day</option>
<option value="1" label="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="2" label="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3" label="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4" label="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="5" label="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="6" label="Saturday">Saturday</option>
<option value="7" label="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
<div style="margin-top:10px">Current trip length:
<b id="output">Please choose days</b>
</div>
```

Comment: where is required output.

Comment: And what should be in output? I set difference, it should be something more?

Comment: @subhra I added output into html. check it now.